# usage of 'other than', 'except' and 'but

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

*Other than, but* and *except* mean almost the same thing: they all introduce an exception to the preceding phrase.

Does what comes after *other than, but* or *except* actually determine which of those needs to be used? Is there some sort of rule?

1. I don't have a pen *other than/except/but* **this.**
2. I don't have an option *other than/except/but* **to go** with her.
3. I don't have an option *other than/except/but* **going** with her.

Comment: This was quite a major edit to bring this question on-topic. 254288, please don't ask "Is this correct?" Focus on **why** something is correct.